# Counting the number of ordered SDRs using the PIE

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Given the sizes of *n* sets, and the sizes of the intersections between the subsets of the *n* sets, is it possible to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion to count the number of ordered systems of distinct representatives for the *n* sets?

Intuitively I think it should be possible. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738667/calculate-the-number-of-sdrs-in-a-i-1-dots-n-setminus-i) question seems somewhat similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fimpellizieri's solution is a sum of $2^{\binom{n}2}$ terms, each with a sign determined by the parity of number of conditions included, and carrying a product of sizes of intersections of certain $A_i$. Whenever two sets of condition determine the same partition of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, they will contribute the same thing to the sum, so we can group these together. This lets us simplify the sum of $\sim 2^{n(n-1)/2}$ terms to a sum of $B_n$ terms, where $B_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Bell number.

Namely, let $P$ represent an arbitray partition of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, with parts $P=\{P_1,P_2,\dots,P_k\}$ for some $k$. Then the number of SDR's is
$$
\sum_{P\text{ is a partition}}(-1)^{n-|P|}\prod_{P_i\in P}(|P_i|-1)!\left|\bigcap_{j\in P_i}A_i\right|
$$
For example, when $n=2$, there are two possible partitions of $\{1,2\}$: either $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ (both in different parts), or $\{\{1,2\}\}$ (both in same part). So it is a sum of two terms, namely,
$$
|A_1|\cdot |A_2|-|A_1\cap A_2|
$$
When $n=3$, there are $5$ partitions of $\{1,2,3\}$:
$$
\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\quad\{1,2\},\{3\},\quad \{1,3\},\{2\},\quad\{2,3\},\{1\},\quad\{1,2,3\}
$$
Resulting in
$$
|A_1||A_2||A_3|-|A_1\cap A_2||A_3|-|A_1\cap A_3||A_2|-|A_2\cap A_3||A_1|+2|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|
$$
Note the $2$ in front of the last term; this is the $(|P_i|-1)!$ in the formula, since the size of the part is $3$.

For a hint of why an alternating sum of ordered pairs of a given partition results in the coefficient of $(n-1)!$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68457/number-of-connected-graphs-on-labeled-vertices-counted-according-to-parity/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike

Comment: I am not sure I understand this answer. If at all possible, could you explain it some other way?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Do you want further explanation of what the formula means (how to calculate it), or the justification for why it is correct? I gave no justification, because I do not know the proof, but I am almost certain it is correct.

Comment: I think I undestand the partition $\{1,2\},\{3\}$ as (in the notation given in my answer) $a_1 = a_2 \in A_1\cap A_2$ and $a_3$ being free to take any value in $A_3$, so that's 'one condition'. In this case, the partition $\{1,2,3\}$ would hence mean $a_1=a_2=a_3\in A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3$, with two conditions, is that so? The coefficient $2$ still seems a mystery to me. Making a parallel with my answer, I could see $a_1=a_2=a_3$ arising from $S = \{B_{1,2}, B_{1,3}\}$, $\{B_{1,2}, B_{2,3}\}$ or $\{B_{1,3}, B_{2,3}\}$. Still, that's an interesting take, and might lead to a more tractable formula.

Comment: Hi @MikeEarnest am I misinterpreting your answer? Given A1 = {1, 2} and A2 = {1, 2, 3}, |A1|⋅|A2|−|A1∩A2| = 4. However, there are three SDRs: {1, 2}, {1, 3}, and {2, 3}

Comment: Does order not matter? Are $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ not distinct? My answer considers them as distinct, and is wrong if that's not the case.

Comment: @ColinMcDonagh I thought that it mattered which set each element of the SDR was chosen from. So $A_1\to 1$ and $A_2\to 2$ would be different from $A_1\to 2$ and $A_2\to 1$. If that is not the case, then my answer is invalid, and the problem seems much harder.

Comment: @MikeEarnest and Fimpellizieri, my apologies, I assumed that SDRs were unordered, I should have been more explicit in my problem statement. I won't be changing the problem statement however (I may just add that the question assumes the order of elements within an SDR does matter). I may then post a question for the unordered variation (unless someone else would like to), and cite this question.

Comment: I have seen the representatives in some sources defined as a set (and hence unordered) and in some sources defined as a sequence (and hence ordered). The 'spirit' of the problem, if one can speak of it, really seems to imply an ordering, though.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Agreed

Comment: I think I understand your answer now. This is pretty smart! +1

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Gotcha, I was in the process of adding more explanation, but I will stop. It's cool to note that the counting we are doing can be thought of as a generalization of the PIE, but instead of indexing over sets, we are indexing over partitions. Both of these are posets, and the PIE for a general poset is called mobius inversions. Usually, mobius inversion refers to the PIE on the poser of natural numbers with divisibility order. You can see the formula in my answer showing up in the last example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra#Examples).

Answer (score 2):

A bad system os representatives can be thought of as a tuple $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ where $a_i \in A_i$ and for some $i\neq j$ we have $a_i = a_j$.

Then, the set of bad representatives can be written as

$$\bigcup_{B \in \mathcal B}B,$$

where $\mathcal B = \{B_{i,j}\,|\, 1\leqslant i < j \leqslant n\}$ and $B_{i,j}$ is the set of bad representatives with $a_j = a_j$.
Therefore, it follows from Inclusion-Exclusion that

$$\left|\bigcup_{B \in \mathcal B}B\right| = \sum_{S\subset \mathcal B}{(-1)}^{1+|S|}\,\left|\bigcap_{B\in S} B\right|.$$

We can break it down by $|S|$.

- When $|S| = 1$, $\bigcap_{B\in S} B = B_{i,j}$ for some $i\neq j$. Now, we can easily compute

$$|B_{i,j}| =
\underbrace{|A_i\cap A_j|}_{\text{choosing the value of $a_i = a_j$}}
\quad\cdot
\underbrace{\prod_{\substack{1\leqslant k \leqslant n\\k\neq i, j}}|A_k|}_{\text{choosing the value of the other $a_k$}}$$

and hence $\left|\bigcap_{B\in S} B\right|$ is known.

- When $|S| = 2$, we are at $B_{i,j}\cap B_{p,q}$ and we have to consider whether the $(i,j)$ and $(p,q)$ have a common index or not.

If they have a common index, say $j=p$ then in the obvious notation we have $B_{i,j}\cap B_{p,q} = B_{i,j,q}$ and

$$|B_{i,j}\cap B_{p,q}| =
\underbrace{|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_q|}_{\text{choosing the value of $a_i = a_j = a_q$}}
\,\,\,\cdot
\underbrace{\prod_{\substack{1\leqslant k \leqslant n\\k\neq i, j, q}}|A_k|}_{\text{choosing the value of the other $a_k$}}.$$

If they do not have a common index, we can compute

$$|B_{i,j}\cap B_{p,q}|
=
\underbrace{|A_i\cap A_j|}_{\text{choosing the value of $a_i = a_j$}}
\cdot
\underbrace{|A_p\cap A_q|}_{\text{choosing the value of $a_p = a_q$}}
\,\,\,\cdot
\underbrace{\prod_{\substack{1\leqslant k \leqslant n\\k\neq i, j, p, q}}|A_k|}_{\text{choosing the value of the other $a_k$}}.$$

In either case, $\left|\bigcap_{B\in S} B\right|$ is known.

---

At this point, I think we got the hang of it.

In general the subfamily $S$ can be partitioned as follows: $B_{i,j}, B_{p,q} \in S$ belong to the same class $C$ if there are $B_{x_1,y_1},B_{x_2,y_2},\dots,B_{x_k,y_k} \in C$ with $\{x_l,y_l\}\cap \{x_{l+1},y_{l+1}\} \neq \emptyset$ for all $1 \leqslant l < k$ and with $\{i,j\}\cap \{x_1,y_1\}, \{x_k,y_k\}\cap\{p,q\} \neq \emptyset$.

It's easy to see that this is an equivalence relation, if the existence of the partition seems unclear.

Perhaps more 'algorithmitically', it can also be seen as the result of a chain of partitions, where the initial partition just makes classes out of pairs $(B_{i,j}, B_{p,q})$ with $\{i,j\}\cap\{p,q\} \neq \emptyset$ and successive partitions aggregates distinct classes when there are representatives from each class with intersecting indices.

Let $P$ be this partition.
For each class $C\in P$, let $I(C)$ be the (union of) the set of indices of the $B_{i,j}\in C$.
Then it's easy to see that

$$\left|\bigcap_{B\in S} B\right| = \left(\prod_{C \in P}\left|\bigcap_{i \in I(C)}A_i\right|\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{\displaystyle i\not\in\cup_{C\in P} I(C)}\left|A_i\right|\right).$$

This means the answer to your question is a resounding **YES**, but a 'closed formula' might be a bit too cumbersome to be actually useful.
Perhaps a different approach might yield a more tractable formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is incredibly helpful. Colin

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.