# Counting the total number of combinations when picking one item each from different sets, and the items have to be unique

Tags: combinatorics

First of all, sorry for inaccurate terms used.

I have been searching on the web but I could not find answers to such problem.

Let's say I have a number of sets of numbers.

Set1 = {0, 1, 2}

Set2 = {1, 2, 3}

Set3 = {0, 2, 4}

I want to find the most efficient algorithm to compute the total number of possible combinations when picking one item each from the above sets without the items being repeated.

Some valid combinations are:

{0, 2, 4} --> 0 from Set1, 2 from Set2, 4 from Set3

{0, 1, 2} --> 0 from Set1, 1 from Set2, 2 from Set3

Some invalid combinations are:

{0, 1, 1} --> 0 from Set1, 1 from Set2, 0 from Set3, but we do not allow repeated 1s

{1, 2, 2} --> 1 from Set1, 2 from Set2, 2 from Set3, but we do not allow repeated 2s

In the above example, the total number of possible combinations is 14 and all the possible combinations are:

{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2 ,4}, {1, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 4}

Is there a formula to compute the total number quickly without having to list all the possible outcomes?

- Will it make it easier if we know that each set is a subset of a known finite set of items (let's say the numbers 0 - 9)?
- What if we have 4 or 5 sets instead of 3 sets? How to generalize the answer for more number of sets (assume the number of sets is smaller than or equal to total number of possible items in each set).

Thank you very much.

Comment: The things you are counting are called systems of distinct representatives, or SDRs. I give a method to count these [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3518994/177399). If there are $n$ sets, you need to sum over all partitions of $n$, which grows like $n^n$. I think this is feasible with up to about $n=12$.